# How to connect to MSSQL from Pentaho?

Tags: java, sql-server, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to connect Pentaho to my local MSSQL server.
I start Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I am promted with this window and then just click Connect:

[image]

I am using Java 8 Update 261 and Pentaho 7.1. I have downloaded MSSQL JDBC driver from following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

and put `mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar` into `pdi-ce-7.1.0.0-12\data-integration\lib` folder. Also I have coppied file `mssql-jdbc_auth-8.4.1.x64.dll` into `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin`...

Now when I start Pentaho via Spoon.bat file, and try to add MSSQL connection, I get errors, furthermore I have no idea what I am supposed to enter into fields:

HOSTNAME:  ?
DATABASE NAME: (name of database is PROFIT)
INSTANCE NAME: ?
PORT: 1433
USERNAME: ?
PASSWORD: ?

[image]

From the picture you can see what I have entered. I also checked `Use Integrated Security` box.
I get following error:

```
Error connecting to database: (using class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)
The TCP/IP connection to the host DESKTOP-CS70NHL, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

Comment: You're using SQL Express edition which can be a bit oddball. It could be listening only on localhost (meaning that other computers on the network cannot connect to it) or it could be listening on a high-numbered port (so connections to tcp/1433 will not connect). Try opening up SQL Server (number) Configuration Manager and checking the TCP/IP settings in Server Protocols. If you make any changes here you will need to restart the SQL Server service for them to take effect.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning OMG OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! Problem was it was using dynamic port number, so I set to fixed 1433, and also TCP/IP protocol was disabled.

Can you post it as answer so i can accept it

Comment: Please copy "mssql-jdbc_auth-8.4.1.x64.dll" to your PDI location "...data_integration\libswt\win64" also.